# Resource usage log

Tags: memory-usage, cpu-load, monitoring

Does Ubuntu register the resources it is using into a log? I need to see the load and RAM usage of a server at a specific time (approximately at 5 AM).

Comment: If you have installed the `sysstat`package `sar` (system activity reporter) will log system utilization every 10 or 20 minutes. Also you could run the commands you usually use for monitoring load from cron at 05:00, and save output to a file.